# Sitecore Graphical setup package for XM Scaled not loading after successful installation

Tags: sitecore-client, installation

I have downloaded `Sitecore 10.2` (Graphical setup package for XM Scaled) from [https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/~/media/0C75EE14B23847FF9C71B3A39B295509.ashx?date=20211101T105422](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/0C75EE14B23847FF9C71B3A39B295509.ashx?date=20211101T105422)

And Installed using SIA. The installation is successful.
When I launch the `Sitecore`, I am getting the error as in the screenshot.

[image]

I was not able to see any errors in the Sitecore log (this is not even created), IIS logs, and Event Viewer.

But the only thing that I am doing is, I just used my `Sitecore 8.1 license into Sitecore 10.2`. Which I am not sure will work or cause any issue like this.

If using the old license will create a problem like this, I can concentrate on getting the new license instead of using the old one.

If using the old license will not be a problem, then it would be great if anyone can put some thoughts to check around.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your IIS, if site is not stopped and also check your host file entry

Comment: IIS is fine and it's not stopped. Host file has proper entry with loop back IP

Comment: Check if you are running website on https then?

Comment: Yes Gaurav. Currently it's in HTTPS which not working.  I have tried with "HTTP" binding as well now. It's the same behavior.

Comment: If you take away the license will it throw any errors? Im interested is the problem on sitecore or somewhere else.

Comment: If sitecore log is not created it means it crashes before it even starts up. Usually this indicates you are missing some necessary SDK that are not installed for example. .NET, ASP.NET. NET Core, IIS Rewrite module etc etc

Comment: I had the same thought. But I ensure that all the prerequisite's are there. It looks like request is not coming to Sitecore and it breaks before that as you mentioned. But no where am able to figure out what's causing this issue. Also when I take out the license file, I get the same error or situation.

Comment: Have you checked from IIS logs that the request goes through all the way to site? So that nothing intercepts it.

Comment: also disable all anti-virus softwares, firewalls everything just in case to see if request gets through

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to the `IIS` site. What you need to check is the following.

1. Is it hosted on `HTTP` or `HTTPS`? And which one you are using in your URL to run this.
2. If it is `HTTPS`, that the site is associated with the particular SSL certificate? Like this

[image]

This can be the issue of certificate.

Comment: It is hosted in HTTPS. Certificate is selected and it's good as well in terms of details and status.

Comment: Ok, I think you need to check windows log viewer. You will get something from there. Please mention here if you find anything.

Comment: There are no errors in windows event viewer under application\system and etc.

Comment: Did you check your host file, if it is not corrupted? or does it have the entry of your site?